# selemium press 'ARROW DOWN' within a box

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying selenium on this website: http://www.panachocolate.com/stockists?

You could see there is an address list on the left side. By default, it lists 100 addresses. If I want to see more, I need to scroll down the box to the very very end to trigger the 'more address' event. I thought it was simple, only 2-3 steps:

1. locate that address box
2. maybe click it?
3. press the arrow down button.

So, with the idea, I come up with the following code(not working):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.panachocolate.com/stockists?')
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ol[@class="storeList rounded-
list"]')
elem.click()
elem.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
# Keys.PAGE_DOWN, Keys.SPACE also won't work
```

It will give the error for both 'click' and 'send_keys method': 'ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not visible'. Am I choosing the wrong element? But there is no other element out there. I tried the last address element as well '//li[@data-value="99"]', but won't work. Any one knows what I missed here? Any suggestions?

Env: Ubuntu, python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the code in python,but i can give you a fair idea on the approach you are looking for.

use Action class to perform the scrolling or move the scroll bar. the code in the Java is as below.

```
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
move.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().‌​moveByOffset(0,numbe‌​rOfPixelsToDragTheSc‌​rollbarDown).release‌​().perform();
```

Or

```
 WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath('//ol[@class="storeList rounded-
list"]'));
 Actions move = new Actions(driver);
     Action action = (Action) move.dragAndDropBy(slider, 30, 0).build();
    action.perform();
```

Or

```
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
//here you specify the condition for the scrolling length 
move.moveToElement(slider).click(slider).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

My apologies, i could not give you exact code in Python, but this approach could help you.

Please let me know if its not working I will try to implement it in java and post the code.

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks for the hint!!! I have worked out the python version and just posted it separately!

Answer (score 0):

So, inspired by @Dharam, I worked out the solution in python. Drag the scrolling bar, it works! Please notice that I changed the browser driver from Firefox to Chrome, as it seems that firefox has some issue dealing with action chain.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.panachocolate.com/stockists?')

while True:
    try:
        # keep dragging till the last address show up
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[@ data-value="2434"]')
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        # grab the sliding bar
        source = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="jspDrag"]')
        # grab any element at the bottom of page 
        target = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="footer-container"]')
        # drag, drag, drag....
        actions.drag_and_drop(source,target).perform()
        time.sleep(1)
```